# Simple python 2.7 code has some kind of issue: "'list' object has no attribute 'find'"

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list, dictionary

The purpose of this code is to return a dictionary that lists the beginning index of a substring in a larger string.

Ex. matchUp(["a", "b, "c", "d"], "abc") would return: {"a":0, "b":1, "c":2, "d":-1} (with -1 being the default empty key)

The hint for this question is that the find function can tell you the beginning index for a substring in another string. This is the correct syntax, right? I have my array of characters in strArray, and y is the substring I am searching for.

```
def matchUp (strArray, word):
    index ={}
    for x in strArray:
        index [x]=-1
    for y in word:
       for x in index:
           if y in strArray:
              index [x]= strArray.find(y)

    return index
```

Comment: Lists don't have a `find` method. That's specific to strings; lists only have `index`. I don't know why.

Comment: I switched the method to index and I did not end up with the result I was expecting. I got -1's across the board for my tests when I should have gotten 0s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `word.find`, not `strArray.find`.

```
def matchUp (strArray, word):
    index = {}
    for ch in strArray:
        index[ch] = word.find(ch)  # <---
    return index
```

(No need to use nested loop)

Usage example:

```
>>> matchUp(["a", "b", "c", "d"], "abc")
{'a': 0, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'd': -1}
```

Comment: That is very confusing to me, but it is correct. so the find method still applies to strArray? It's just that it needs to be oriented with the string it comes from?

Comment: why `strArray.find` (or `strArray.index`)? You want the index of characters (a, b, c, d) in `word`, not in `strArray`. ?

Comment: @grilam14, You'd better to consider: `matchUp(["a", "b", "c", "d"], "cba")`. In original example, a, b, c appear in same order; which maybe caused confusion.